# Do I need a visa to visit to Spain with my Spanish wife as a non-EU citizen?

Tags: visas, spain, spouses, spanish-citizens, palestine-citizens

I'm a non-EU citizen with Palestinian nationality, married to a Spanish citizen. We got married a few weeks ago in Palestine (we both live in Palestine). She travels to Spain regularly to visit her family there.

We're in contact with the Spanish consulate in Palestine to get our marriage recognized and get the Libro de Familia.

How can we visit Spain? Do I need a visa and, if so, which type?

The purpose is just travel, to visit the country, at least for now.

Comment: You need a Schengen or Spanish national visa.

Comment: Might find this useful https://eumovement.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/no-visa-but-still-want-to-travel/

Comment: @SamJones EU law does not generally apply to family of a member state's own citizens, although Spain does seem to extend similar rights to Spanish citizens' family members.  Still, the MRAX decision is unlikely to be helpful since it won't generally be possible for a Palestinian to reach the Spanish border without a visa; he will need the visa before boarding his flight.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a visa.

You may be able to get it free of charge because Spain apparently extends to family of its own citizens rights similar to those extended to the family of European Union citizens.

You say you are already in contact with the Spanish consulate.  You should ask there to apply for a visa as the spouse of a Spanish citizen.

Comment: So, what I need to do is to apply for a Schengen visa as the spouse of an EU citizen. That is after getting my marriage recognized by Spanish authorities and getting the Libro de familia.

Comment: @Palio that looks about right, except that Spain may have different categories for family of Spanish citizens and family of other EU citizens.  For example, the application doesn't need to be free of charge.  So you should say that you are married to a *Spanish* citizen, not to an *EU* citizen.  (I believe Spain actually treats these categories identically, but they are not required to, and I do not know for sure exactly how they handle it.)

Comment: I see! I couldn't find any other type of Visa related to my case other than the Schengen visa. and they actually do not mention how they treat spouses of Spanish citizens. so this is a cause of undecidedness at this point.
For instance, Do I need to show bank statements, payment slips or an employment certificate? it's unclear.

Comment: @Palio Schengen visas are not particularly segregated by type.  There's basically one visa, the short-stay visa, which can be granted for any of several reasons.  So you apply for a Schengen visa as a tourist, a business visitor, or a family member.  If they process the application as they would for an EU spouse, then no, you would not need to show bank statements or the like.  The consulate should be able to tell you how to proceed.

Comment: Ok many thanks. I will contact the consulate and keep this post updated.

Answer (score 1):

I visited the Spanish consulate. They asked for minimum info, no finances etc. They just asked for international health insurance. I will get the insurance and send them my passport by mail. I'll keep the post updated.